Conundrum in continuity equation of simple 1D transport
Here's a simple 1D transport problem. Define $f(x)$ to be the PDF of the standard normal distribution i.e. $f(x) = \mathcal{N}(x \mid 0, 1) = {1}/{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-x^2/2)$. Then, define a constant velocity field $v(t, x) = 1/f(x)$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and over the time interval $t\in[0, 1]$. I'm interested in solving the probability density $p(t, x)$ of the transport under this velocity field with the boundary condition $p(0, x) = f(x)$ i.e. the initial distribution is the standard normal.
Now, the continuity equation (Thm. 5.34 in Villani, 2003) says that the solution uniquely satisfies the following PDE:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\mathrm{div} (pv)
\end{align}
Consider a candidate solution $p(t, x) = f(x)$. It clearly satisfies the continuity equation since the divergence $\mathrm{div}(pv) = \mathrm{div}(f(x) \frac{1}{f(x)}) = 0$. The solution suggests says that the density remains unchanged with time. But the velocity field $v(t, x)$ is always positive, and is moving the probability mass along the positive x-axis.
I'm unable to reconcile how a velocity field that always flows in the same direction doesn't move the probability distribution. I would've expected the Gaussian to move along the positive x-axis. What am I missing? Is my example violating some regularity constraints needed by the continuity equation?

Your function $1/f$ has singularities at $\pm \infty$. Informally speaking, this means that you move mass from $-\infty$ to the real axis, mass on the real axis to the right, and mass from the real axis to $+\infty$. Therefore, the probability density does not change in your example.
Edit:
Another possibility to understand this, is to consider an interval $I = [a,b] \subset \mathbb R$.
Then, one can check that $\int_I p(t,x) \, \mathrm d x$ is constant. The reason is that the mass flowing in at the left boundary equals the mass that flows out at the right boundary.
Hence, all the mass travels to the right, but at any point in space, the density does not change.

I don't fully understanding this answer; it seems a bit too informal/handwavey. Do you mean the PDF of the standard normal $f(x)$ has singularities? It's a smooth density function that falls exponentially to zero as you move towards $\pm \infty$. Or do you mean that the velocity field $1/f(x)$ has singularities? Also what do you precisely mean by "singularities"?

Yes, I mean $1/f(x)$ goes to $\infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

I added a further paragraph. Maybe this helps?
